# R: Deleting Row doesn't shift data up for certain .csv but does for .xls file

Tags: r, row, delete-row

I was interested in looking at GDP of a few states over a span of 4 years. After I imported the .csv file, I renamed the column names and then removed irrelevant rows. The result is that the data skips the 10th row when numbered. So it goes from 1 to 9, then starts at 11.

When I tried this with a similar dataframe I imported from a .xls file, the data does not skip the 10th row when numbered.

```
gdp<-read.csv("GDP_per.csv",skip = 4)
gdp<-gdp%>%
  rename(
    "2014" = X2013.2014,
    "2015" = X2014.2015,
    "2016" = X2015.2016,
    "2017" = X2016.2017,
    "2018" = X2017.2018
  )
gdp<-gdp[c(-(10),-(53:64)),]


gdp2<-read_excel("GDP_dol.xls", skip = 5)
gdp2<-gdp2[,c(2,20:24)]
gdp2<-gdp2[c(-(10),-(53:64)),]
```

**9**
Delaware
10.7
5.5
-0.7
2.5
3.9

**11**
Florida
4.9
6.5
5.0
4.4
5.8

vs.

**9**
Delaware
67178.9
70896.2
70379.8
72167.2
74973.3

**10**
Florida
839706.0
894044.0
938370.3
979464.6
1036323.2

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read.csv` function returns a data.frame while `read_excel` returns a tibble. They are not the same and do not necessarily behave the same way. A data frame retains the original row names until you change them, e.g.

```
(x <- data.frame(V1=1:10, V2=11:20))
(x2 <- x[-5, ])                # Row name 5 is missing
rownames(x2) <- NULL
x2                             # Row names 1 - 9
```

A tibble automatically renumber the rows:

```
library(tidyr)
xt <- tibble(x)
(xt[-5, ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `read_csv()` function from the `readr` package which imports it as a tibble thus resulting in the same behaviour.